# Meaning of $E$ in time-independent Schrödinger's Equation (high school)

Tags: energy, schroedinger-equation

I've just learned the time-independent Schrödinger's equation as

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\cfrac{d^2\psi(x)}{dx^2}+V(x)\psi(x)=E\psi(x).$$

Does $E\psi(x)$ mean that **$E$ is a constant** (that the kinetic energy of a particle is constant) or **is $E\psi(x)$ a separate function of $x$**?

Comment: Yes, the energy here (is the energy of the whole configuration) is a constant. This is why it is a stationary state.

Comment: I think you have missed some constant factor  like h and i and mass m of the particle and E is the energy of the particle under the potential interacting with it-usually chosen a priory...

Comment: Have a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations.

Comment: IMHO other answers didn't get OP's question. He's asking if $E\psi$ is
the symbol of a different function, or if $E$ is just a
*multiplicative* constant (of course it's the latter). But what's the
sense of exposing high-school students to such matters?

Comment: I would say that it depends on his mastery of physics/mathematics. We can't assume much just from the fact that he's in high school. I am a high schooler that has some knowledge of quantum mechanics and (partial) differential equations, which I mention because they are both relevant to this question. More specifically, I have experience with using separation of variables to solve Schrodinger's equation, hermiticity of various operators such as the Hamiltonian, creation and annihilation operators, and enough knowledge of commutators to prove the general uncertainty theorem, among other topics.

Comment: *Continued*. I think we should encourage high schooler who are interested in physics to pursue it and ask questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation is indeed the time independent Schrödinger Equation for a single particle in one dimension ($x$). Yes, $E$ is the total energy of the particle.

To better appreciate this abstract looking equation, students are often taught the so-called Particle in a Box, system. [Here's a good text dealing with that system.](https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Physical_Chemistry_(McQuarrie_and_Simon)/03._The_Schrodinger_Equation_and_a_Particle_In_a_Box/3.5%3A_The_Energy_of_a_Particle_in_a_Box_is_Quantized)

Comment: Yes, the Particle in the box is indeed what we used to demonstrate the equation, and I was confused because E seemed to be considered a constant. As a follow-up question, how do we even determine E? Is $\Delta$E just not considered?

Comment: @Sooyoung Cheong If you want to ask a follow up question, either edit your post so that more people can see it, or ask another new question.

Answer (score 2):

$E$ is a constant, although this is ducking over a lot of important details. It represents the total energy of the system, not just kinetic.

Comment: I can't understand your correction. Ok for wrong sign, but why did you
change $d$ with $\partial$? Function $\psi$ depends only on a single
variable. What's the meaning of a partial derivative?

Comment: Oh, the OP revised his question. I was addressing a earlier version where there were obvious issues.

Comment: I'm sorry. Sometimes it's useful to be allowed to
reedit previous posts or answers, but it's liable to upset time
sequence and confuse causal connection.